# Render preview vs Render issue with hair

Tags: particles, shape-keys

I have added a strip of eyelashes on a small skin strip that is surface deformed (modifier) to each eyelid. I added a shapekey to close the eyes, so the eyelid and the eyelashes move.

Strangely in render preview the lashes move nicely with the lid but when I render it it stays in the place it is without the shapekey. Anyone know why? (Left is render preview, right is rendered). Also I am confused why the hair is so much different than the preview hair, but that might be related to bsplines or so and does not bug me as much as the eyelashes not moving.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it took me 6 minutes to figure out both issues, so maybe I should have put some thought into it before asking.

[image]

The eyelid mesh had a multires modifier on it because i duplicated it from the main mesh in edit mode and it took its modifiers. The preview was at 0 and the render view was at 1. The binding is related to the amount of vertices so it only works in the mode that it was bound, which was 0. So it showed nicely in render preview but not in render. The strange hair was from a different hair emitter that I forgot to delete and that was hidden in the viewport but not in the render.